# Make sure basic floating point operation calculations are accurate

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a procedure in my SQL Server database which is supposed to get the `@FinalProfit` and update `ProfitRate` based upon its value.
So here is how `@FinalProfit` is calaulated whenever it is required as outcome of a procedure

```
[1] SET @FinalProfit = (ProfitRate(a % value) / 100) * SoldPrice
```

Now that my procedure gives me `@FinalProfit` and I have `SoldPrice` stored, the following code must logically be able to fill `ProfitRate` and I must be able to reproduce `@FinalProfit` whenever I want.

```
[2] CAST(((@FinalProfit / SoldPrice) * 100) AS DECIMAL(15,2))
```

However, after running procedure with a `FinalProfit` like 50, when I try to reproduce `@FinalProfit` later on using **[1]**, I get a value like 49.94 as a value which is obviously not what I want especially when dealing with prices.

I know this problem has to do with how floating point calculations are done yet I have no solution for it.

EDIT:
In order to create a reproducible sample of this problem:
Content of each item sale info in saleinfo table:

```
ID SoldPrice ProfitRate
1 300.00    0.0000
2 300.00    0.0000
3 325.00    0.0000
4 400.00    0.0000
5 500.00    0.0000
```

The code I use whenever I want to select `@FinalProfit` from this table

```
SELECT (ProfitRate / 100) * SoldPrice AS FinalProfit
FROM saleinfo
WHERE ID = 1
```

The procedure code I use to update the profit rate to match my desired final profit

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[inlineedit]
    (
    @InvoiceItemID      INT,
    @FinalProfit      DECIMAL(15,2)
    )
AS
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN
        IF @FinalProfit IS NOT NULL
            /* 
            This buyers premium is not a % based number. thus we have to calculate what percentage should be stored
            as we change final ProfitRate payment amount.
            */ 
            UPDATE [dbo].[LotSale]
            SET ProfitRate =  
                CASE WHEN SoldPrice <> 0 AND SoldPrice IS NOT NULL THEN CAST(((@FinalProfit / SoldPrice) * 100) AS DECIMAL(15,2))
                ELSE 0
                END 
            WHERE LotID IN (
                SELECT L.LotID
                FROM dbo.Lot AS L
                    INNER JOIN dbo.LotSale AS LS ON LS.LotID = L.LotID
                    INNER JOIN dbo.InvoiceItem AS II ON II.LotSaleID = LS.LotSaleID
                WHERE II.InvoiceItemID = @InvoiceItemID
            )  
    END
    COMMIT ;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION ;
    DECLARE @TErrMsg NVARCHAR(1000) ;
    SET @TErrMsg = (SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrMsg) ;
    RAISERROR(@TErrMsg, 18, 1) ;
END CATCH ;
GO
```

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] which allows us to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @DaleK Done sir not sure if the code works 10% correctly since the procedure itselft was too long and Ive used only a section of it here to show the problem.

Comment: Please don't call me (or anyone on this site) sir, stick to gender neutral pronouns.

Comment: I don't want to see you code, I want you to provide an example of a set of values that when calculates using the different methods returns a different result. Should be as simple as 2 sets of numbers - or similar.

Comment: Ok sure my bad. I though it's a common pronoun used for respect. I'm genuinely sorry if you're offended.  I thought I mentioned it in my question an example like this. 
For you answer, when I call procedure with input of 50 I get 50.01 as output whnever I try to recalculate the Final Profit @DaleK

Comment: On additional notes, this problem, as I have seen up till now, only occurs when the final profit of my procedure is a number like 10, 20, 30, a multiple of 10 if you will. this problem isn't produced for 15 as an example. @DaleK

Comment: Aside... you said "floating point" and "accurate" in the same context. Floating point and Real data types are approximate numerics, ref: [float and real (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/float-and-real-transact-sql). They definitely shouldn't be used anywhere that accuracy is important such as, say, financial calculations.

Comment: Cast your data to decimal before doing division.

Comment: The solution you suggested worked for me however I don't understand why. thanks for your answer anyways @Charlieface

Comment: Because otherwise the division is done using floating-point math not binary decimal math, and therefore subject to rounding errors